# git master behind remote master (in a not normal way)

Tags: git

The server where the git repo origin/master lived died and apparently the automated backups of origin/master had broken many commits ago. So this is where things get weird.  The origin/master was restored to this old backed up version that doesn't actually have all the recent commits, but I have all the commits and the true version of the current repo on my remote/master (on my local machine).  I thought maybe I could just do a git push but I get

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.teamsnap.io:marketing/marketing-production.git'
```

so the issue is my local master is actually ahead of origin and Im scared to do a "git pull" (I have not made any local commits, when I run "git status" there is nothing staged.  My thinking is that the commits that I have locally that the master repo doesn't have will get overwritten?)

```
origin: A--B--C--D--E
```

(F and G are gone because origin repo was restored from a old backup that did not have all commits)

```
remote: A--B--C--D--E--F--G
```

How do I get my local remote/master to restore origin/master? I feel like there is a simple fix but am nervous since I have only true version history. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just answering with a magic formula (because there is no single correct magic formula), here's a long answer that describes what's happening and what you need to think about....

#### Distributing repositories

We start with the notion that Git is a DVCS: a Distributed Version Control System.  A typical Git repository often has many copies ("clones"), which start out identical to the original—or mostly identical; see below—then both may grow apart over time as new commits are added to the original, or new commits are added to the clone.

Note that as a general rule, commits are never *removed*.  Of course, a crash, and subsequent restore-from-backup, can easily result in removals.

Note as well, however, that we (necessarily) add new commits *after* existing commits, just as in your diagrams.  Suppose we have a three-commit repository, where the three commits are simply:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- master
```

Here the name `master` identifies the most recent commit `C`.  (It does so by remembering the big ugly 40-character SHA-1 hash "true name" of the commit, `c123456...` or whatever.)  Commit `C` then identifies commit `B` (by its true name, `b123456...` or whatever), and commit `B` identifies commit `A` (by its true name).

The process of adding a new commit is simple in principle: we write (or Git writes) blobs and trees for a new commit as needed, and then write the new commit object into the repository.  This new commit has the current commit's ID—the "true name" of commit `C`—in its parent field.  Writing the commit produces a new big ugly hash; let's just call it `D` here.  Git writes the new hash into the current branch (in our case, `master`), and now we have:

```
A <- B <- C <- D   <-- master
```

Since we know new commits have to point backwards in history to older commits—that's the only way it *can* be done, because commits are *immutable* (in fact all Git objects are immutable)—there's no real need to draw in the intermediate arrows and we just write:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

Of course, at some point, we might *clone* this repository.

The new clone looks exactly like the original.  How can we tell which one is which?  Well, obviously we *know* which was the original; and it's not like the new clone is conscious and wonders if it is the original or the copy. :-) But for our convenience, the `git clone` command sets up the copy with two extra bits of information, and one big change:

- added: a *remote* named `origin` (or some other name you choose)
- added: underneath that remote, where `git config --get remote.origin.url` will be able to retrieve it, the URL we gave to `git clone`
- changed: all of the branches get *renamed* from their original names (such as `master`) to so-called *remote-tracking branches*: `master` becomes `origin/master`, `develop` (if there was one) becomes `origin/develop`, and so on.

This last change is significant, but it has no effect on any *commits*, whose "true names" are the big ugly hashes.  Commits store parent commit IDs under these true names, which never change.  Moreover, since the true name of each commit is simply a checksum of its contents, *every Git everywhere in the universe* will have the same "true name" for any bit-for-bit identical commit.  In fact, this is true for any internal Git repository object: blob, (annotated) tag, tree, or commit.<sup>1</sup>

It's this last trick that enables the **D**istributed part of the DCVS.  Every Git server everywhere agrees that the true name of a six-byte file containing the word "hello\n" is `ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a`. If you don't have this file in your repository, `ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a` is probably<sup>2</sup> not a valid hash, but if you do, it is the ID of that file.

---

<sup>1</sup>The hashes are currently 160-bit SHA-1 hashes, and changing this would be difficult, but in principle any non-invertible, reasonably-secure cryptographic hash suffices.  The rest of this answer assumes Git continues to use SHA-1.

<sup>2</sup>The probability that you can find some *other* object with this same hash is about one out of 2<sup>160</sup>, which is ... well, let's just say "very tiny", unless you come up with some way to defeat the cryptographic hash.  Then you can (at least try to) construct a file that deliberately breaks Git.

---

#### Synchronizing Gits

Once you have a clone or two, and the users with clone start adding commits, they will naturally add *divergent commits*.

Suppose the original has, as in your example, five commits which we can call `A` through `E`:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
```

Now Alice and Bob both clone this, so they get the same thing except that `master` is renamed to `origin/master`.

The last thing each of their `git clone` commands does is to `git checkout master`, which uses special `git checkout` logic to discover that there is one `origin/master` and no `master`, and hence make a new branch `master` pointing to the same commit.  So they now have this:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master, origin/master
```

Now Alice makes a new commit, which we'll call `F`:

```
A--B--C--D--E     <-- origin/master
             \
              F   <-- master
```

and Bob makes a new commit, which we'll call `G`:

```
A--B--C--D--E     <-- origin/master
             \
              G   <-- master
```

The "true name" hashes for `F` and `G` are quite different and all three Git systems—the one on the original server `origin`, the one on Alice's computer, and the one on Bob's computer—can therefore tell them apart, even though only Alice's computer has `F` now and only Bob's computer has `G` now.

This is where `git push` comes in.  Let's say Alice tries to push first.

#### `git push` super-summarized

Alice runs `git push origin master`.  Her Git calls up the server's Git (using https, or ssh, or whatever protocol, but probably over the Internet, anyway).  Her Git finds out from the server that the server's `master` points to commit `E`.  Because commits are immutable and the server's `E` matches Alice's `E`, Alice's Git now knows that the server has `A` through `D` as well.  Alice's Git can therefore send just commit `F`.<sup>3</sup>  (This is where you see messages about "counting" and "compressing" and "writing objects".)

Now, near the end of the push operation, Alice's Git sends the server a polite request: "Please set *your* name `master` to point to commit `F`."  This is where you see either a success or a failure—and for a failure, typically something like just what you are seeing:

```
[rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

This is because, for each request (a non-force push), the server's Git checks to see if the request—in this case, "set `master` to point to commit `F`—is a normal "add new commits" style operation.<sup>4</sup>

If it *is* a fast-forward, the push will be allowed.  If it's *not*, the push will be rejected by default.  Of course, Alice's push *is* a fast-forward: adding `F` is quite normal, and the server does it.

Now it's Bob's turn.  When Bob's Git calls up the server's Git, Bob's Git discovers that their `master` is commit `F`, which Bob doesn't have.

If Bob were doing a `git fetch`, Bob would get commit `F` from the server.  But Bob is doing a `git push`, so Bob's Git goes on to send commit `G`.  Commit `G`'s parent is commit `E`, which Bob's Git and the server's agree that the server already has; so Bob's Git sends *only* commit `G`.  Let's draw the resulting graph, as seen from the server.  I will leave the downward kink in it and put `G` upward:

```
              G   [no name yet]
             /
A--B--C--D--E
             \
              F   <-- master
```

Then Bob's Git goes on to say: "now, please set `master` to point to commit `G`".

What happens if the server does this?  Well, we can draw it:

```
              G   <-- master
             /
A--B--C--D--E
             \
              F   [uh oh...]
```

This is where things go bad: the server still has commit `F`, for the moment, but if it moves the name `master`, it may no longer have a *name* for commit `F`.

Commits `E` back through `A` are safe: the name `master` lets Git find commit `G`, and `G` finds `E`, and `E` finds `D` and so on.  But poor commit `F` gets abandoned.

This would be a *non-fast-forward*, and by default, the server rejects the attempt.

Using a force-push tells the server that it should change the branch name target anyway, despite the non-fast-forward.  But if the server does that, *its* copy of commit `F` is in fact abandoned.<sup>5</sup>  Git's garbage collector (`git gc`) can then run and remove it entirely.

Note that if the server *does* lose commit `F`, Alice probably still has it in her clone.  That may be the only place to get it, or perhaps other users ran `git fetch` and picked up commit `F`.  But it's not a *safe* thing to do—who knows if Alice even still has her clone at all?

---

<sup>3</sup>In fact, it has to send commit `F`, *and* objects needed by `F` (trees and blobs) that are not already on the server as implied by the existence of `E`.  There's a whole have/want protocol that is used as needed here for shallow repositories as well, but that's a complication we can ignore.

<sup>4</sup>Specifically, the test here is a *fast-forward* test.  While you normally see this in the context of `git merge`, fast-forward is actually a property that applies to branch name movements, along the commit graph—the `A--B--C` stuff we've been drawing.  A label motion is a fast-forward if the new target of the label has the old target of the label as one of its ancestors.

That is, if we go back to drawing these as `A<-B<-C<-D<-E`, the test here is: "`master` used to point to `E`.  You ask me to point it to `F`.  Can I, starting from commit `F`, walk along the various arrows and arrive at commit `E`?  If so, changing `master` in this way is a fast-forward operation.  If not, it's not."

<sup>5</sup>On a clone, references normally have something called *reflogs* enabled.  These reflogs keep track of the previous commit values stored in each reference.  Reflog entries do eventually expire, but this gives you—by default—at least 30 days to "resurrect" any ostensibly-abandoned commit.

Server Git repositories generally don't have reflogs turned on (or did not back when I ran a bunch of servers, in the Git 1.7 era; I have not yet checked to see if this has been updated since then).

---

#### This is where `git merge` and/or `git rebase` come in

Just for some completeness, I'll mention these here, but not describe them very fully.  What Bob should do at this point is to run `git fetch origin`.  This will bring over, into his clone, commit `F`, and make *his* `origin/master` point to it:

```
              G   <-- master
             /
A--B--C--D--E
             \
              F   <-- origin/master
```

Bob now has, in his repository, everything he needs to make sure that his commit `G`, or something equivalent and good-enough, can be pushed *without* losing commit `F`.  Bob can *merge* commits `G` and `F` into a new merge-commit:

```
              G
             / \
A--B--C--D--E   H   <-- master
             \ /
              F     <-- origin/master
```

and then push both `G` and `H` to the server, and ask the server to move its `master` to point to commit `H`.  This will be OK,<sup>6</sup> because the server's `master` at `F` will now be in the history of `H` (as a merge commit, `H` points back to both `G` *and* `F`).

Or—usually better—Bob can use `git rebase` to *copy* `G` to a new commit, `G'`, which is a lot like the original `G` except that it starts from Alice's code and has, as its parent commit, commit `F`:

```
              G   [abandoned]
             /
A--B--C--D--E   G'  <-- master
             \ /
              F     <-- origin/master
```

Now, again, Bob can have his Git push `G'` (not `G` this time!) and the server can set it and then everyone—server and Bob both—can forget about the original `G` and just pretend that there's a nice straight line of commits that now reads:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- master, origin/master
```

(Bob's abandoned original-G commit will be garbage-collected after a month or so.)

Note that whether Bob merges or rebases, after Bob successfully pushes, it's now Alice who needs to `git fetch` to pick up the new commit(s).

---

<sup>6</sup>Well, it will as long as Bob is quick enough to get this all done before someone else pushes something else!

---

#### What this means for your recovery process

When the Git repository on your server was restored, it was restored to some older version.  As in your example, it may have had:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- master (on server and on clone)
```

in it before the server died.  After the server was repaired and restored, it would have fewer commits:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master       (on server)
```

If this were still the case and you were on some clone that had `F` and `G` and you did a `git push origin master`, it would just work: adding `F` and `G` back would be a fast-forward operation.  The fact that it *didn't* work means that this picture must be inaccurate.

Most likely, after the restore but before you could `git push` from some better clone, *someone else* came along and added one or more new commits after `E`:

```
A--B--C--D--E--P--Q--R   <-- master   (on server)
```

During your push of:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G      <-- master   (on clone)
```

the server will temporarily construct this graph:

```
              P--Q--R   <-- master
             /
A--B--C--D--E
             \
              F--G      [proposed update for master]
```

If you force the push, the server will "forget" the `P--Q--R` chain, abandoning it.  Probably *some* client *somewhere* has it, but that's the risk (*do* they have it, and if so, will they know to keep it?).  Instead, you can `git fetch` *from* the restored server and get this *same graph* into your own repository, just with some different labels:

```
              P--Q--R   <-- origin/master
             /
A--B--C--D--E
             \
              F--G      <-- master
```

Now you can decide how to handle this: you might move `P-Q-R` onto the end of `G`, for instance.

#### Force with lease

There's one remaining problem that can occur, no matter how you decide how to fix this up.  Whether you really do want to throw out some commit(s), or merge them, or rebase them, at some point you—using your clone repository—will want to push or force-push to the server.

If you just want to push normally, everything is great: your push succeeds because it's a fast forward, or fails because someone else beat you to it, and you must `git fetch` again and re-figure-out what to do.  But what if you decide that it's time to "rewrite published history"?

That is, suppose you decide, as in the previous example that you wish to keep the `P--Q--R` chain but add it on after `G`.  You can *merge* these and get a normal push (and that might be the way to go).  Or, you can use `git rebase` to *copy* them to *new* commits, affecting whoever pushed the original `P--Q--R` sequence (because they wind up having the originals and, after `git fetch`ing, the copies too)—and affecting anyone else who's picked up the `P--Q--R` sequence in the time period it's been on the server.

Anyway, assuming you've decided on a force-push and you've done this in your own clone:

```
              P--Q--R          <-- origin/master
             /
A--B--C--D--E
             \
              F--G--P'-Q'-R'   <-- master
```

you can now `git push --force origin master` to send `F--G--P'-Q'-R'` over and *tell* (rather than ask) the server to move *its* master.

But what if someone else managed to push commit `S` just before *your* push?  Sure, you copied `P--Q--R`, but now you will lose `S`.

This is what `--force-with-lease` is for.  With `git push --force-with-lease`, you have your Git send a sort of "half-force command":

"I believe that you, Mr Server, have your `master` pointing to commit `R`.  If so, I say you shall set your `master` to new commit `R'`!"

The server can always refuse anyway (see pre-receive and update hooks), but now its default action is to *check*: "Does my `master` point to `R`?  It does?  OK, Mr Client, now it points to `R'` instead!"  Or: "Does my `master` point to `R`?  No?  Well, sorry Mr Client, I'm not changing anything here."

This gives you the ability to change the server's `master` *if and only if* it's still set up the way you saw it.

#### One last alternative

Instead of all of this fussing around on clients, there is one possibly-better method.  If you can *log in* directly on the server, you can *disable* pushes entirely for a while.  You can then also just run Git commands directly on the server if needed.  This gives you an easy way to hold everyone off and make sure they don't use out-of-date server information.  (You might even disable *fetch* from the server during the "unstable" period, so that only people who know how to log in directly, and use Git commands directly on the server, can read from the somewhat broken / historically-rewound server repository.)

(Whether this is feasible and reasonable depends quite a bit on the nature of the server.)